# Trying to drop the contents of one Word document into another

Tags: ms-word, drag-and-drop, office-interop, clipboard

This is in an IDTExtensibility2 (not VSTO) Word AddIn. I'm trying to do a drag drop where I programatically give the contents of one document to DoDragDrop(). The problem is instead of dropping the contents in the other document, it inserts it as an embedded Word document.

My code is basically:

```
srcDoc.Activate();
activeWindow = srcDoc.ActiveWindow;
selection = activeWindow.Selection;
selection.WholeStory();
selection.Copy();
data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
DragDropEffects effect = DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Scroll);
```

How can I have it paste the contents instead of pasting the document?

Please note, I want to paste all of the content in the source document into the insertion point of the drop in the destination object. So it's not copy over the full contents of the destination (therefore a file based approach won't work).

And it's drag/drop so I don't have the control that Clipboard.Paste() provides to specify the pasting format. In addition, the format I need is the native DOCX format to bring all properties & formatting across.

thanks - dave

Comment: Are you dragging Word doc _contents_, or a file from Windows Explorer?

Comment: @Nyerguds - neither. We are doing this inside our Word AddIn code. So it's all calls to the Word COM API.